# Is it possible to trigger jQuery datepicker element on both input click and button?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have an input text containing a default date and I'm using jQuery's Datepicker plugin to select a date from a popin calendar. This calendar pops in when the user clicks on the small picture next to the input.

This is working great but I'd like to trigger the calendar's popin even when the user clicks on the input text. Long story short, I want the calendar to be displayed on both evenements.

Is it possible ? How ?

Thank you !

Comment: I tend to agree with Nick, but seeing the code you have working right now may also be helpful.

Comment: I was looking for something complicated, trying to trigger some custom action or even instantiating 2 calendars on one element... It reminds me that sometimes the answer is right under my nose ;) thx everyone

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You just need to set the [`showOn` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOn) to `"both"` (rather than `"focus"` or `"button"`), like this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

[You can try it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/tK6Hy/).

Answer (score 1):

Try to trigger the button event in the input event handler, something lik ethat:

```
jQuery("#myinput").click(function(e){
    jQuery("#mybtn").trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: That's not just roundabout, but unnecessary as well. And a duplicate of an earlier answer.

Comment: yes, missed it. Strange, I just saw the kinjal's one. Salping my face myself.

Answer (score 0):

write the same click handler you are writing for the image/link id, but this time with the textbox id.